# How to Check if an List Item has a certain Child Div Within It?

Tags: jquery, html, selector, parent-child

How can I check if a div with an id of #showLogo is present within the parent li with a class of 'image-rollover'? I can't use children().length because the number of children will vary for this list item. Is there any way to directly check based on the id of the div?

What I need is something like this:

```
$('li.image-rollover a').mouseover(function() {
    if ($(this).children('#showLogo')) { 
    showLogo();
    } else { 
    hideLogo();
    }       
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with `$(this).children('#showLogo').length`?  That should only ever be 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a context?

```
$('li.image-rollover a').mouseover(function() {
    if ($('#showLogo', this).length) { 
        showLogo();
    }
    else { 
        hideLogo();
    }       
});
```

Remember that there should only be one `#showLogo` on the page.

Answer (score 1):

See the following:

**https://jsfiddle.net/JokerDan/m8n5ay1a/**

Using the `.is` method within JQuery allows you to see if an element has a specific .class, state (such as *:hidden*) or #id among other things.

In this example there is a small list in which when you roll over the item with the id defined (in this case, '#showLogo') you will get an alert to say that the ID has been detected. Simply swap out the alert for the code needed and complete the 'else' logic!

```
$('li.image-rollover a').mouseover(function() {
  //console.log($(this).is('#showLogo'));
  if ($(this).is('#showLogo')) {
    alert("Roll Over Has ID 'showLogo'");
  } else {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear with your question.. but try

```
$('#showLogo').parent().hasClass('image-rollover')
```

Comment: I am trying to call a function named showLogo() only if a list-item element contains a div within it that has an id of #showLogo, if it does not contain that div, I want it to call the function hideLogo()